# Find the index of twitter bootstrap's tab using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap's tab layout. For each tab i have attached click event handler. Inside the click handler i wanted to find out the index of the tab that is clicked. Below is by code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $(".nav.nav-tabs > li > a").on('click', function (e) {

        var index = $(".nav.nav-tabs > li > a").index(this);

        // do something here
    })
```

The above code works as long as i have single `nav-tabs` layout on the same page.
But if i have multiple `nav-tabs` on the same page the above code may not return correct index or even if it returns correct index the code is not optimized to look only inside clicked `nav-tabs`.

I can scope the jquery select by passing `id` or custom class name. However i'm trying to find if there is generic way to find the index of clicked `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `.nav-tabs` which contains the clicked element using [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method and check index within the children element.

```
var index = $(this).closest('.nav.nav-tabs').find('> li > a').index(this);
```

```js
$(".nav.nav-tabs > li > a").on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).closest(".nav.nav-tabs").find('> li > a').index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul><ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul><ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Or get the index of `li` element within the siblings where `li` can get using [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.

```
var index = $(this).parent().index();
```

```js
$(".nav.nav-tabs > li > a").on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).parent().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this exmaple

lets say you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul>

    <li><a href="#fragment-2">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-4">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

then you can get clicked tab index like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Tab initialization
$('.tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
        var tabNumber = ui.index;
        var tabName = $(ui.tab).text();

        alert('Tab number ' + tabNumber + ' - ' + tabName + ' - clicked');
    }
});
});
```

please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mZLDk/1718/)